# How do I pass a variable via drupal_goto()?

Tags: 6, redirection

So I have a function having `http://link/to/$id` as destination link.

It works when I use `<a href="?q=mymodule/option/$id">Targeted</a>`.

But I need to change it to submit form because I need to pass more than one `$id`. So, I thought it was good to use `drupal_goto()` rather than the link option.

```
drupal_goto('mymodule/option/$id');
drupal_goto('mymodule/option/'.$id);
drupal_goto('mymodule/option/', $id);
```

Those are not working. It always go to http://link/mymodule/option without passing `$id` variable. How do I do this correctly?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! So, what is the content of `$id`, if `drupal_goto('mymodule/option/' . $id)` doesn't work? I take it is not similar to `drupal_goto('node/1')` since that would work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume your url is like in this example:

```
http://example.com/somepage?param1=val1&param2=val2
```

In that case you can take values of `param1` and `param2` like so:

```
$param1 = $_GET['param1'];
$param2 = $_GET['param2'];
```

You may use this parameter for drupal_goto as

```
drupal_goto("path_here", array("param1" => $param1, "param2" => $param2));
```

**For Drupal 7:**

As [YPCrumble says](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/181172/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-via-drupal-goto/181173?noredirect=1#comment303785_181173) you need to use this code:

```
drupal_goto("path_here", array("query" => array("param1" => $param1, "param2" => $param2)));
```

For more details, refer to the [API Documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/6).

Comment: Shouldn't this be `drupal_goto("path_here", array("query" => array("param1" => $param1, "param2" => $param2)));`? It didn't work for me when I didn't specifically include the `"query"` argument.

Comment: @YPCrumble this is for Drupal 6, you have Drupal 7?

Comment: ah I see - thanks for the clarification! Hopefully my comment will help someone with D7 :).

Comment: @YPCrumble I will edit the answer with your code ;-)